# Gray arrows and stop signs on folders

Tags: directory

What are those gray arrows and stop signs on folders? I assume the latter is linked to protected, but what about arrows?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Stop signs are on files and folders your user don't have access to. The arrowed folders look like system tools and libs.

Comment: symolic links..